# Using Inheritance on Kendo Widget Helpers has impact on performance?

Tags: asp.net, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I was looking into the Kendo Widgets we use in our project. We use the same widgets again and again and I was wondering about the benefits we could have if we used custom Html Helpers where we could group some attributes. 
An example of what I was thinking is this:

```
public static DropDownListBuilder MyCustomDropDownList(this HtmlHelper helper, Models.Specialty model, string dataCascadeFunction)
    {
        ResourceService resource = new ResourceService();
        return helper.Kendo().DropDownList()
                .DataTextField("Name")
                .DataValueField("Id")
                .OptionLabel("Select Specialty")
                .Events(evt => evt.Open("clearFilterOnDdl"))
                .DataSource(source =>
                {
                    source.Read(read =>
                    {
                        read.Action("GetCascadeSpecialties", "AcAdmin")
                            .Data(dataCascadeFunction)
                            .Type(HttpVerbs.Get);
                    })
                    .ServerFiltering(true);
                })
                .Filter("contains")
                .MinLength(3)
                .Text(model != null ? model.Name?? string.Empty : string.Empty)
                .Value(model != null ? model.Id ?? string.Empty : string.Empty);
    }
```

Then I call it from my view like this

```
@(Html.MyCustomDropDownList(Model.Specialty, "filterSpecialties")
                .CascadeFrom("OperationType_Id")
                .Name("Specialty.Id")
            )
```

What I am doing is just setting some default custom settings in order to save some lines of code and to make my code cleaner. I was wondering if this use of the Html helpers has any good or bad impact on the performance of my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The demonstrated approach to reuse default custom settings of Kendo UI HtmlHelpers is valid, and will have no performance impact.